# How to Reply That PASSPORT NUMBER is not in my remembrance at the moment

Tags: phrases, expressions

If somebody called me over phone and asked to give your Passport number / Pan card / Roll number something. If it is not in my remembrance , how can I apologies in best way for this ?

NOTE -Please do not answer the straight forward  English Sentences . i want to know best options to communicate my inability to provide something which is not in my remembrance.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That seems like someone trying to con you.

Comment: I am afraid that my {   } is one of the many pieces of information that I do not keep in my working memory. I can obtain it for you later.

Comment: What to you mean with >> NOTE -Please do not answer the straight forward English Sentences?? What language would you like the answer in?

Comment: This might be a good candidate for ELL.

Comment: Are you sure, you mean "remembrance" in your question? haha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can say:

> I'm sorry, I do not know that number by heart. I need to look
>   it up and get back to you.

Never give data like passport number, credit card number, account names or passwords on the phone.

> I'm sorry, but I'm not prepared to provide that information on the phone. Please contact me in writing.

Comment: Why by heart? why not in mind?

Comment: In the second case i'd just say, "that's privileged information" or "not your business"

Comment: In the U.S., at least, “I don’t know that off the top of my head” is an idiom similar in meaning to “I don’t know that by heart.”  I would use either one particularly for numeric information (e.g., a phone number or account number) or information with a numeric component (e.g., a date/time or address).  These are applicable for the sorts of things that one might _memorize_, but that one would not be expected to _know_ –– for example, the home phone number of a co-worker who isn’t a close friend.

Comment: A related idiom: “It’s on the tip of my tongue” –– is used for information that you know, but cannot remember.  This is commonly used, for example, when you cannot recall the name of a person you know reasonably well.  Yet another that I encountered for the first time just a few weeks ago (I believe that it was on [Super User](http://superuser.com)): “I have that on the edge of my memory.”  I guess it’s similar in general meaning, but I’m not familiar with it, so I can’t speak to the nuances.